# How to access execution_date in SimpleHttpOperator in Airflow

Tags: rest, jinja2, airflow, databricks

I am trying automate a call I make using a [REST API](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/01%20Databricks%20Overview/10%20REST%20API.html) with the SimpleHttpOperator.

Here is an example of the call I can make and is working great.

```
curl -u username:password 
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
    -X POST 
    -d '{"job_id":10,"date":{"year":"2016","month":"10"}}' 
    https://MY_INSTANCE_NAME.cloud.databricks.com/api/2.0/jobs/run-now
```

Now, formatting this to be generated by the SimpleHttpOperator looks like this and also works great:

```
t2 = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id=TASK_ID,
    http_conn_id=CONN_ID,
    method='POST',
    endpoint='api/2.0/jobs/run-now',
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    data=json.dumps({"job_id":10, "date": { "year": "2016" , "month": "10" }}),
    dag=dag
    )
```

I now am trying to access execution_date, a variable set by Airflow which lets an Operator know the time it was suppose to be called. This normally is accessible using a jinga template for BashOperator or PythonOperator but not SimpleHttpOperator:

```
e.g. """echo {{execution_date}}"""
```

This variable is not available to the SimpleHttpOperator and it is very much needed. If you know any work arounds or a way to access it within the SimpleHttpOperator, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The date field in SimpleHttpOperator accepts jinja template:

```
t2 = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id=TASK_ID,
    http_conn_id=CONN_ID,
    method='POST',
    endpoint='api/2.0/jobs/run-now',
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    data="""{"job_id":"10", "date": { "year": {{code}}, "month": {{code}}{{'}}'}}""",
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: what should be the value of `CONN_ID`